# regarding the possible approaches of performing conda install locally due to the firewall issue

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I was trying to install python packages in the anaconda, and it got the followign errow messages. I  think it is because our organization just update our firewall system. Are there any ways to use conda install locally, e.g., download related anaconda package, and install it locally. If it is possible, how to do it? Thanks.

```
(devenv) C:\>conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -
An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64'
```

Comment: Sidenote: They recently changed the package name to just `prophet`. See https://github.com/conda-forge/prophet-feedstock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use pip to install via anaconda prompt
[ref](https://pypi.org/project/fbprophet/) -

```
conda deactivate
conda activate <your_environment_name>
pip install fbprophet
```

Also based on the error returned, it suggests re-trying.